# How to delete all database entries except for one in Django?

Tags: sql, django

I have a model called Countries, and a model instance was created for each country.  How can I delete all countries except for one?

Can I do something like

```
Countries.objects.all().exclude(name="us").delete()
```

Or am i going to have to use raw sql?

Comment: Erm, you can do exactly that. Did you try?

Answer (score -1):

You can try iterating over the instances and only delete ones that don't meet your criteria.

```
for country in Contries.objects.all():
    if country.name != "us":
        country.delete()
```